# Unable to Install Erlang using asdf on OSX 10.15.4

Tags: xcode, macos, erlang, build-tools, asdf-vm

I am running into an issue that I haven't previously had with over 6+ months of using asdf on osx. I need to install Erlang 21.3.7.1 and when I do I get this error output from the console that I honestly don't know how to solve:

```
Me@My-MacBook-Pro:~/Code/codebase|master
⇒  asdf install erlang 21.3.7.1
Downloading kerl...
Downloading OTP-21.3.7.1.tar.gz to /Users/Me/.asdf/plugins/erlang/kerl-home/archives
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   124  100   124    0     0    523      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   523
100 51.5M    0 51.5M    0     0  8541k      0 --:--:--  0:00:06 --:--:-- 9657k
Extracting source code
Building Erlang/OTP 21.3.7.1 (asdf_21.3.7.1), please wait...
DOCUMENTATION INFORMATION (See: /Users/Me/.asdf/plugins/erlang/kerl-home/builds/asdf_21.3.7.1/otp_build_21.3.7.1.log)
 * documentation  :
 *                  fop is missing.
 *                  Using fakefop to generate placeholder PDF files.

Build failed.
 GEN obj/x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0/opt/MADE
 LD /Users/Me/.asdf/plugins/erlang/kerl-home/builds/asdf_21.3.7.1/otp_src_21.3.7.1/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0/erl_child_setup
ld: weak import of symbol '___darwin_check_fd_set_overflow' not supported because of option: -no_weak_imports for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[4]: *** [/Users/Me/.asdf/plugins/erlang/kerl-home/builds/asdf_21.3.7.1/otp_src_21.3.7.1/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0/erl_child_setup] Error 1
make[4]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[3]: *** [opt] Error 2
make[2]: *** [opt] Error 2
make[1]: *** [smp] Error 2
make: *** [emulator_profile_generate] Error 2
```

Nothing I found on the Erlang/Elixir/asdf forums was particularly helpful. asdf was installed with homebrew. I can install the ref:maint build and change my .tool-version to match but that sets off a whole slew of other issues with Crypto and openssl not being found even though they're installed. Anyone have an idea or two?

Comment: I'm running into this exact same issue. I'll let you know if I find a solution.

Comment: If you google, there are solutions to the openssl issue, but I think the weak import is another issue altogether.

Comment: I think the reason this doesn't show up in a simple google search is that `-no_weak_imports` instructs Google to _exclude_ results containing `no_weak_imports`. Adding double quotes around the entire error message leads directly to the relevant Jira issue. (and now also this question)

Comment: also same message during compiling gnutls30-shlibs-3.6.13-1 via gcc 10.1.0 and Xcode command-line tools: 11.4.1.0.1.1586360307.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not possible to build Erlang 21 on Catalina (10.15), according to the comments in [this bug report](https://bugs.erlang.org/browse/ERL-1205).  You can use release 22.3.1 or later.

If you need to use an older Erlang version, you could try applying [this change](https://github.com/erlang/otp/pull/2577/files) on the Erlang 21 source code.

Comment: Yep, I upped to 22.3.1, and it resolved my issue, which was the same issue OP was running into.

Comment: Cheers! Bummed out by it but this did answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading to Catalina I tried installing 22.3.1 but that was not enough for me; somehow Erlang on Catalina could not find `OpenSSL`.

What I had to do was:

1)  Uninstall Erlang 22.3.1 if you have it already:

```
asdf uninstall erlang 22.3.1
```

2) Update Xcode to latest version & accept agreement

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

3) Set `--with-ssl` flag ([copied from the asdf-erlang readme](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-erlang#dealing-with-openssl-issues-on-macos))

```
export KERL_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS="--without-javac --with-ssl=$(brew --prefix openssl)"
```

4) Reinstall Erlang

```
asdf install erlang 22.3.1
```